# Bicep ADF LinkedService

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-bicep, linked-service

I'm having a heck of a time trying to deploy a simple Azure BlobFS linked service into an ADF using Bicep (which I have only really started to learn).

The bicep I have thus far is:

```
//---Data Factory
resource datafactory 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name: adf_name
  location: loc_name
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    globalParameters: {}
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
  }
}

//--- Data Factory Linked Service
resource adls_linked_service 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices@2018-06-01' = {
  name: 'ls_adf_to_adls'
  parent: datafactory
  properties: {
    annotations: []
    connectVia: {
      parameters: {}
      referenceName: 'AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime'
      type: 'IntegrationRuntimeReference'
    }
    description: 'linked_service_for_adls'
    parameters: {}
    type: 'AzureBlobFS'
    typeProperties: {
      accountKey: datafactory.identity.principalId
      azureCloudType: 'AzurePublic'
      credential: {
        referenceName: 'string'
        type: 'CredentialReference'
      }
      servicePrincipalCredentialType: 'SecureString'
      servicePrincipalId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      servicePrincipalKey: {
        type: 'SecureString'
        value: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
      tenant: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      url: bicepstorage.properties.primaryEndpoints.blob
    }
  }
}
```

The ADF resource deploys fine by itself as does the ADLS (symbolic name is: bicepstorage). The issue is when I added the linkedservice resource block. I get:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: /home/vsts/work/1/s/psh/deploy_main.ps1:12
Line |
  12 |  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | 22:46:27 - The deployment 'main' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of
     | 1 error(s). Status Message: Input is malformed. Reason: Could not get
     | integration runtime details for AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime
     | (Code:InputIsMalformedDetailed)  CorrelationId:
     | f77ef878-5314-46ea-9de6-65807845a104
```

The only integration runtime in the ADF is the 'AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime'. When I inspect it in the portal it's green, running and healthy.

I'm using task: AzurePowerShell@5 on ubuntu-latest in ADF, but I get the same error when I try to deploy the template directly from vscode.

I'm out of ideas and would really appreciate some assistance. I found the documentation for the 'connectVia' block (actually all the documentation on bicep linked services!) to be really confusing; if anyone could tell me exactly what is supposed to go in there, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#default-azure-ir), If you want to create a linked service to adls(blobfs) with default Azure IR (autoresolveintegrationruntime) then you can remove the `ConnectionVia` property in linked service block in your bicep template.

[image]

To test this I have created a bicep template which will deploy adlsgen2 storage account, data factory and a linked service to it using the service principal based authentication.

**Here is the sample template for your reference**:

```html
param location string='westus'

//---Data Factory
resource storage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01'={
  name:'<storageAccountName>'
  location:location
  kind:'StorageV2'
  sku:{
    name:'Standard_GRS'
  }
  properties:{
    accessTier:'Hot'
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly:true
    isHnsEnabled:true
  }
}
resource datafactory 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name: '<AdfName>'
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    globalParameters: {}
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
  }
}
//--- Data Factory Linked Service
resource adls_linked_service 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices@2018-06-01' = {
  name: '<linkedserviceName>'
  parent: datafactory
  properties: {
    annotations: []
    description: 'linked_service_for_adls'
    parameters: {}
    type: 'AzureBlobFS'
    typeProperties: {
      url: storage.properties.primaryEndpoints.dfs
      //encryptedCredential:storage.listKeys(storage.id).keys[0].value
      servicePrincipalCredential: {
        type: 'SecureString'
        value: '<serviceprincipalKey>'
      }
      servicePrincipalId:'<serviceprincipalappId>'
      servicePrincipalCredentialType:'ServicePrincipalKey'
      azureCloudType:'AzurePublic'
      servicePrincipalKey: {
        type: 'SecureString'
        value: '<serviceprincipalKey>'
      }
      tenant: '<tenantId>'      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, this cleared the issue. I had simply copied the template linkedservice typeproperties from the documentation (where is said: 'use this') and proceeded to fill in the values. 

Seems odd that completing the connectVia using the default autoResolveIntegrationRuntime would result in an input error, no? Relying on it defaulting to the IR has worked for me, but I could see a situation where it would be useful to be able to express, in config, explicitly what IR I want it to use.